# Importing vv survey file. Exclude Response ID's failure [Limesurvey]

Tags: sql-server-2012, response, limesurvey

Again, an issue with Limesurvey. Seems like  if "Exclude Response ID's" is checked, it doesn't play any role in import. I am saying this, because I tried 2 ways of importing responses to survey:

1. I exported survey and imported it as new one. I also exported responses (Export .VV file) from old survey. Then I activated new survey and tried to import responses (from old one) with "Exclude...ID's?" checked - I get an error. In SQL profiler, I see that during import, at the last point of it, there is INSERT statement and it tries to insert id value(s), but id column has IDENTITY property, which cannot be updated and nothing could be inserted in that column. Am I describing limesurvey bug or it is just an issue, because I use SQL Server 2012? Maybe somebody, who has different database (MySQL or other) could try this? Don't be surprised, but the same thing (during import with "Exclude Response ID's" checked,tries to insert response id) happens, if there are already one or more responses in that survey and their id's doesn't match any of id's from the file, which I want to import. Would I be wrong if I say that this option shouldn't look at response id at all and should just import responses,simple as that?
2. Next situation is when "Exclude..." isn't checked with option "Replace existing record". If in the survey there is already at least one response with the same id as in my vv file, the response from survey is deleted (Step one of this option) but nothing is inserted. Well, with profiler I see more or less the same situation as in earlier described problem - it tries to insert response id, but id column in the table has IDENTITY property. What could be done here? If I remove IDENTITY property, I could bring much bigger problems with that. Also, I don't know, if I should report this as a bug.

Yes. There are two more options, but nothing new with those - it tries to insert id if response id in the file doesn't find any match in responses' id from survey.

Well, there were few questions, but the main is:

1. The option "Exclude Response ID's" - does it work properly, as it
   should? If yes, explain in a few sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working with mysql and pgsql .

See https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/helpers/admin/import_helper.php#L4623

Time to report a bug at http://bugs.limesurvey.org